# Firefox headless --print-to-pdf option

Tags: firefox, headless

Does Firefox headless include the option to print to PDF ? Chrome headless supports it, but im not sure if Firefox does.

Comment: Relevant bugzilla ticket https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1407238

Answer (score 3):

I don't seem to find any reference to printing to PDF for Firefox headless mode. However, there's an [option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Headless_mode) to take a screenshot of the page since Firefox 57:

```
/path/to/firefox -headless -screenshot https://developer.mozilla.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print to PDF by using GeckoDriver.

For example, using the Node.js Selenium bindings, you can write a script like this one:

```js
(async function() {
  const {Builder} = require('selenium-webdriver');
  const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
  const {writeFileSync} = require('fs');

  let options = new firefox.Options().addArguments('--headless');
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').setFirefoxOptions(options).build();

  try {
    await driver.get(process.argv[2]);

    let printResult = await driver.printPage({background: true, width: 21.0, height: 29.7}); // A4
    let printResultDecoded = Buffer.from(printResult, 'base64')

    writeFileSync(process.argv[3], printResultDecoded);
  } finally {
    await driver.close();
  }
})();
```

And then simply invoke it like so:

```bash
node pdf-driver.js https://example.com/URL/TO/PRINT ./PDF-RESULT.pdf
```